# Modifying references to lists

Tags: python

For an algorithm I'm benchmarking I need to test some portion of a list (which could be very long, but is filled with 0's mostly and the occasional 1). The idea is that in a list of n items, with d of them being of interest, in expectation each is defective with probability d/n. So, check a group of size d/n (it's defined in terms of the floor and log functions for information theoretic reasons - it makes the analysis of the algorithm easier).

Algorithm:

1./ If n <= 2*d -2 (ie more than half the list is filled with 1s) just look at each item in turn

2./ If n > 2*d -2: Check a group of size aplha (= floor(binarylog(l/d), l = n - d + 1, d = number of 1s). If there is a 1, do binary search on the group to find the defective and set d = d - 1 and n = n - 1 - x (x = size of the group minus the defective). If there isn't a one, set n = n - groupSize and go to 1 (i.e. check the rest of the list).

However, when populating the list with 10 1s in random places, the algorithm find all but a single 1 and then continues to loop whilst checking an empty list.

I think the problem is that when discarding a group containing all 0s I'm not correctly modifying the reference that says where to start for the next round, and this is causing my algorithm to fail.

Here is the relevant part of the function:

```
import math

def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList)

    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid]
        if any(lower):
            high = mid
        elif any(upper):
            low = mid + 1
        elif mid == 1:
            return mid
        else:
            # Neither side has a 1
            return -1

    return mid

def HGBSA(inList, num_defectives):

n = len(inList)
defectives = []

#initialising the start of the group to be tested        
start = 0    

while num_defectives > 0:
    defective = 0
    if(n <= (2*num_defectives - 2)):
        for i in inList:
            if i == 1:
                num_defectives = num_defectives - 1
                n = n - 1
                defectives.append(i)
    else:
        #params to determine size of group
        l = n - num_defectives + 1
        alpha = int(math.floor(math.log(l/num_defectives, 2)))
        groupSize = 2**alpha
        end = start + groupSize
        group = inList[start:end]
        #print(groupSize)
        #print(group)
        if any(group): 
            defective = binary_search(group)
            defective = start + defective 
            defectives.append(defective)
            undefectives = [s for s in group if s != 1]
            n = n - 1 - len(undefectives)
            num_defectives = num_defectives - 1
            print(defectives)
        else:
            n = n - groupSize

        start = start + groupSize    

print(defectives)
return defectives
```

Also here are the tests that the function currently passes:

```
from GroupTesting import HGBSA

#idenitify a single defective
inlist = [0]*1024
inlist[123] = 1
assert HGBSA(inlist, 1) == [123]

#identify two defectives
inlist = [0]*1024
inlist[123] = 1
inlist[789] = 1
assert inlist[123] == 1
assert inlist[789] == 1
assert HGBSA(inlist, 2) == [123, 789]

zeros = [0]*1024
ones = [1, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801, 901]
for val in ones:
    zeros[val] = 1
assert HGBSA(zeros, 10) == ones
```

I.e. it finds a single 1, 2 and 10 1s deterministically placed in the list, but this test:

```
zeros = [0] * 1024
ones = [1] * 10
l =  zeros + ones
shuffle(l)
where_the_ones_are = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 1] 
assert HGBSA(l, 10) == where_the_ones_are
```

Has exposed the bug.

This test also fails with the code above

```
#identify two defectives next to each other
inlist = [0]*1024
inlist[123] = 1
inlist[124] = 1
assert GT(inlist, 2) == [123, 124]
```

The following modification (discarding a whole group if it is undefective, but only discarding the members of a group before the defective) passes the 'two next to each other' test, but not the '10 in a row' or random tests:

```
def HGBSA(inList, num_defectives):

n = len(inList)
defectives = []

#initialising the start of the group to be tested        
start = 0    

while num_defectives > 0:
    defective = 0
    if(n <= (2*num_defectives - 2)):
        for i in inList:
            if i == 1:
                num_defectives = num_defectives - 1
                n = n - 1
                defectives.append(i)
    else:
        #params to determine size of group
        l = n - num_defectives + 1
        alpha = int(math.floor(math.log(l/num_defectives, 2)))
        groupSize = 2**alpha
        end = start + groupSize
        group = inList[start:end]
        #print(groupSize)
        #print(group)
        if any(group): 
            defective = binary_search(group)
            defective = start + defective 
            defectives.append(defective)
            undefectives = [s for s in group if s != 1 in range(0, groupSize//2)]
            print(len(undefectives))
            n = n - 1 - len(undefectives)
            num_defectives = num_defectives - 1
            start = start + defective + 1
            #print(defectives)
        else:
            n = n - groupSize
            start = start + groupSize  

print(defectives)
return defectives
```

I.e. the problem is when there are multiple 1s in a group being tested, and after the first none are being detected. The best test for the code to pass, would be the 1s uniformly distributed at random throughout the list and all defectives are found.

Also, how would I create tests to catch this kind of error in future?

Comment: I suggest using any ide that allows you to set breakpoints and use a debugger. In such a environment finding errors like this one would be trivial

Comment: I'm using spyder but can't figure out how to use pdb.

Comment: What is the first `inList.index(1)` supposed to do? It is just finding the index of the first 1, then ignoring it.

Comment: I use eclipse + pydev. Setting a breakpoint and previewing values is a no-brainer

Comment: @DanielRoseman inList.index(1) - that is supposed to find 1s in the case where the list is not sparse.

Comment: Well, it finds the first one. But OK, so say it's found those values, what are you doing with them?

Comment: Index(1) gives you the index of the first 1. However, since you don't assign this value to anything, it is lost. Once you find the first 1 there, what did you want to do with it?

Comment: The `else: return -1` is dead code. Take it out, and make the `elif` an `else`. It's clearer that way.

Comment: At the moment the index(1) isn't tested and am I'm not focusing my work on it. I plan to replace it with a filter statement to find all 1s in the case where the test passes.

Comment: @user2357112 the if and elif tests are required by the algorithm, I have 3 cases to check. Returning -1 is to indicate that both these tests have failed.

Comment: If `n <= 2*num_defectives -2` is True, your code will loop forever.

Comment: Please provide a runnable (i.e. complete) fragment of code that can be executed for testing.

Comment: @TomKealy: There is no third case. It is not possible for both the `if` and the `elif` checks to fail; your `elif` test is true if and only if the `if` test is false. I don't think you understand what your algorithm is doing.

Comment: @user2357112 The algorithm is supposed to check groups smaller than n/2 (where n is the length of the list) - in fact 2^alpha (alpha defined above) - to identify 1s in a very sparse list (2^10 + long). Whether the elif/else thing remains isn't really that important (this isn't production code), I just need to check that less than half the list is populated with 1s. But this isn't really relevant to the question I asked.

Comment: @martineau the problem is that the algorithm won't find 2 1s located within the same group. I can modify the function to pass the 2 located next to each other by including start = start + defective + 1 into the if any(group) section and removing the start = start + groupSize at the end of the while loop, but the function then fails to find 10 equally spaced 1s.

Comment: Also to add: this code is only for testing a mathematical idea - I'm not so bothered about testing every use case (like having a list with more than half 1s) at the moment - I just need to find more than one 1 in group (i.e. two placed next to each other).

Comment: Sorry, your code is still not runnable, after fixing the indentation errors, an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment` on the statement `if(n <= 2*num_defectives -2):`. I don't think it's reasonable for you to expect much help if you can't even to be "bothered" to provide runnable code to us.

Comment: @martineau sorry, that one slipped by me.

Comment: @martineau also sorry about the indent issue: I'm struggling with the submission box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm seemingly has worse performance than a linear scan.

A naïve algorithm would just scan a piece of list the size of d/n in O(d/n).

```
defectives = [index for (index, element) in enumerate(inList[start:end], start)]
```

Common sense says that you can't possibly detect positions of all 1s in a list without looking at every element of the list once, and there's no point in looking at it more that once.

Your "binary search" uses `any` multiple times, effectively scanning pieces of the list multiple times. Same applies to constructs like `if any(group): ... [s for s in group if ...]` which scan `group` twice, first time needlessly.

If you described the actual algorithm you're trying to implement, people could help troubleshoot it. From your code and your post, the algorithm is unclear. The fact that your `HGBSA` function is long and not exactly commented unfortunately does not help understanding.

Don't be afraid to tell people here the details of *what* your algorithm is doing and *why;* we're sort of computer geeks here, too, we're going to understand :)

Comment: I couldn't share the details until the legal team at my uni had given this the all clear! But you *can* detect the positions of the 1s - the list is 1024 long and contains only 10 1s (i.e. it's sparse). The analysis (see Comninatorial Group Testing - Hwang, Du) is that O(dlog(n)) is the best we can do. That is done by testing a group of size (roughly) d/n (say by binat xor or any) and then performing a binary search on any groups that have a 1 in it. My code fails if there are 2 1s in a group. This is like the coins and pan balance questions in maths books.

Comment: Also: thanks for the one liner above - it's *much* better than anything I've come up with this week!

Comment: Well, you _have_ just formulated what you're doing: a probabilistic combinatorial test (all without breaking any NDAs). Please update your question! But with vector size of 1024 you're probably better off just scanning everything, unless testing an element is _demonstrably_ expensive. The machinery you've built may have a bigger overhead than is your gain from not scanning every element. In general, make a correctly working naive implementation first, profile, optimize later _if needed_. Often it's OK as is.

Comment: Question updated with algorithm. I was going to optimise etc once the code above passed the 'randomised' test I posted originally. I was also going to change 1024 to something bigger (but this is really a demonstration rather than a piece of production code).

Comment: I still can't see if doing [adaptive tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing) is possible in your case. The binary search is only efficient when you can say that a defect is in a group can be analyzed all at once, like blood samples fused together, coins weighed together, etc. Does _this_ property apply in your case?

Comment: For my purposes a group is just a vector (or a list) containing 1s and 0s. Yes, I am doing combinatorial GT, and this is the state of the art deterministic algorithm for that. http://www.math.sinica.edu.tw/post-doctor/hbchen/1_sequential_alg.pdf has a section on my algorithm. If ou have a better way than any() to test the groups I'd be really interested.

Comment: The paper you refer to assumes presence of group tests cheaper than a full scan; in a vector, you don't have one! Try approximation techniques: e.g. if the distribution of 1s is known to be uniform by position, scan a sample and use the 'concentration of 1s' figure to extrapolate to the full vector length. But if you call `any(some_list)`, you effectively do a full scan of the list. If you do `foo = bar[start:stop]`, you already do a scan of `bar` from `start` to `stop` just to make the copy. You generate _lots_ of overhead. Maybe doing a full scan via `numpy` will the fastest solution.